# Where to Put ORDER BY to Sort Query in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sql-order-by

I currently have the following formula below that works in filtering results based on custom inputs that the user makes. I am trying to add a sort function on top of it...

However, I am a bit lost on when I should be placing the ORDER BY function to allow me to do this. Where can I add ORDER BY to this? Is my syntax incorrect?

Apologize in advance if this is an easy solution, I'm new to Google Sheets.

=QUERY('2 - CC RAW'!1:1000,"SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "&IF(B3="ALL PHASES",""," AND LOWER(H) CONTAINS LOWER('"&B3&"') ")&IF(B4="NONE",""," AND LOWER(L) CONTAINS LOWER('"&B4&"') ")&IF(ISBLANK(B5),""," AND LOWER(C) CONTAINS LOWER('"&B5&"') "), 1)

I tried to place the ORDER BY function in various places, but yielding either errors or nothing happening to the queried data.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=QUERY('2 - CC RAW'!1:1000,"SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "&
      IF(B3="ALL PHASES",""," AND LOWER(H) CONTAINS LOWER('"&B3&"') ")&
      IF(B4="NONE",""," AND LOWER(L) CONTAINS LOWER('"&B4&"') ")&
      IF(ISBLANK(B5),""," AND LOWER(C) CONTAINS LOWER('"&B5&"') ")&
      "order by C desc,H", 1)
```

- for reference `C` is sorted *descending* (1st priority) & then `H` *ascending*

Answer (score 0):

The `order by` clause comes after the `where` clause, like this:

```
=query(
  '2 - CC RAW'!A1:Z, 
  "where " & textjoin(" and ", true, 
    "1 = 1", 
    if(B3 = "all phases", "", "lower(H) contains lower('" & B3 & "')"), 
    if(B4 = "none", "", "lower(L) contains lower('" & B4 & "')"), 
    if(isblank(B5), "", "lower(C) contains lower('" & B5 & "')"), 
  ) & 
  "order by A", 
  1 
)
```

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).